# How to use two date types in form?

Tags: php

Well basically I'm now working on contact form, and I need to add two dates types. User can specify which date they will use in a profile, and then it uses if statement to show exact date type (American or European) in form. That is easy, I can do it with if statement, but next is saving date type to database. Well basically my database table is timestamp, and saving European time is easy, but how about American time? Well basically, in my form for american time there is a hours ( 1 - 12 ), minutes ( 1 - 60) and period ( AM and PM ), well basically 3 select inputs, so any ideas, how could I convert them to 24 hour time and then save to database as European date?

Have done already everything with European date, now only American time left.

Hope you understood what I ment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. I would not store the formatted  time. Store a UNIX timestamp and the *name* of the format you want to use. Then you just have to format the time for the output and don't have to worry about how to store it.

Comment: I think you can add +12 to the hours, if PM is selected and you can then convert it into the timestamp

Comment: Well yeah, exactly what I ment, how can I format the time for the output? Well basically if it's hours 11, minutes 34 and period AM, how can I change it to 24h time? And same with PM.

Comment: Hmm, gonna try to do that. Let me check

Comment: Doesn't PHP have any kind of Date object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime` its can convert between any date & time format you want

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y","03/32/2012");
echo $date->format("d-m-Y"); // You can use any format
```

OR

```
echo $date->format("U"); // Timestamp
```

If you want to use functions only

```
$date = date_create_from_format("m/d/Y","03/32/2012");
echo date_format($date, "d-m-Y");
```

For documentation on different formats : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Hmm, seems interesting, but I can't get it to work on Wordpress. Do you know, is it allowed on Wordpress also, or there is any similar function for wordpress?

Comment: I would update my answer in a moment but you can look at see http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time using `the_date()` and `the_time()`

Comment: Thanks ;)! I will check it in a moment, hmm it seems the_time() function only displays the date, not change it to different format.

Comment: Also look at http://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-to-change-wordpress-date-format.html it gives details on how to change wordpress date format

Comment: Hmm, well basically I guess that is not what I need, I will stick to dateTime function, but I get error - Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object . Is there anything I must include?

Comment: what version of PHP are you using  .. you can also try the function approach

Comment: PHP version 5.3.8 about date_create_from_format and date_format, it gives me error-  Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given

Comment: It should work .... did you change anything in the code ??? like the date it self ???